# Saving image to disk and loading them

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have a painting flex project (web, run on browser) and I'd like to save the images in a local user folder (`/AppData/` or `/Documents/`) and load them to edit them again. How can I achieve that? Since its not an Air application, I'm not sure about what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an SWF, embedded in a web page, you can use:

```
ExternalInterface.call("functionName", param1, param2);
```

Just make sure the function is available to the SWF to call. ie the "`<script>function functionName(param1, param2){}</script>`" lies on the same page as your embedded SWF.

Seen [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ca8.html).

From this script you can then do as you require.

Answer (score 0):

You can save and load images through [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) class. It has methods `save()`, `browse()` and `load()`. First method opens dialog box where user can save file (that you generate in code before) on local machine. browse() opens dialog box where you user can pick file to load (you can determinate supporting file types) and load() loads chosen file like a ByteArray.